# Pass existing data to different view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, view, handlebars.js

While in `/` view, I get documents from mongodb and create a list item for each document that only shows the date and the first few words. I want to be able to click on each list item to go to a new page, `/view`, to see the rest of that particular document.

To do this, I believe I need to pass `item` between `/` and `/view`, then access the properties of `item` there. How do I do this with the `pagelist` function (or without it)?

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var app = express();
var hbs = exphbs.create({
  helpers: {
    message: function() {return 'Welcome!';},
    doc: function() {return "Something went wrong.";}
  }
});
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');  
var util=require('util');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/users';
const dbName = 'users';
var db;  
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
 assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  db = client.db(dbName);
  db.collection("reviewYelp2", { }, function(err, coll) {
        if (err != null) {
          console.log(err)
          db.createCollection("reviewYelp2", function(err, result) {
                assert.equal(null, err);  
      });
    }

    db.ensureIndex("reviewYelp2", { document: "text"}, function(err, indexname) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
    });

  });
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) { 
    res.render('search');
});

app.get("/view", function(req, res) {
    // NEED TO BE ABLE TO ACCESS CLICKED ITEM HERE 
    res.render('viewItem', {
        // Change to access item.text when I have access to item
        helpers: {
            doc: function() {return "Viewing doc...";}
        }
    });
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {  
    db.collection('reviewYelp2').find({
        text: new RegExp(req.body.query)
    }).sort({date: 1}).toArray(function(err, items) {
        res.render('search', {
        helpers: {
            message: function() {return pagelist(items);}
        }
    });
  })
});

function pagelist(items) {  
    result = "<ul>";
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        // Grab only first 10 words of text
        textSlice = item.text.split(" ");
        textSlice = textSlice.slice(0, 5);
        text = textSlice.join(" ");
        str = "<li class="+item._id+"><a href='/view'>" + item.date + "    " + text + "...</a></li>";
        result = result + str;
    });
    result = result + "</ul>";
    return result;
}

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("App listening on localhost:3000");
});
```

search.handlebars:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form method="post">
   <input type="text" size="80" name="query" />
   <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submitButton" />
   {{{ message }}}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

viewItem.handlebars:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="window.history.back()">Go back to list</button>
   {{{ doc }}}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problematic because http is fundamentally stateless — that is each request to the server is it's own thing. You can come up with schemes involving cookies or local storage, but I think a simpler approach is both better and more common.

A simpler idea is to have a route that takes some sort of id parameter:

```
app.get("/view_detail/:itemID", function(req, res) {
    var item = req.params.itemID 
    // lookup detail about item based on itemID
    res.render('viewItem', {
        // send data
    });
});
```

Now on index you can have a list of links that look like :

```
 /view/878743 (or whatever scheme you have for db keys) 
 /view/36764e
```

Comment: @briennakh  You should have the ids in the the data you are using to create the list of links in index. It sounds like you have a list of things the user can click on all pointing at `/view`. You just need to put the id in the url of the links the user is clicking on - `/view/someID`.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to make it work with `/view?reviewID=239752` where the number is the ID, and then accessing it in the view with `req.query.reviewID`